# Can you combine 3 CTE's into one?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a query written with 3 CTE's and I need to get the exact same result using only 1 CTE. Can someone help me?

```
WITH Q1(cid, sumEP) AS
(
    SELECT customerid, SUM(Extendedprice) 
    From "Invoices" 
    GROUP BY customerid 
), Q2(cid, oid, mf) AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT customerid, orderid, freight 
    FROM "Invoices" 
), Q3 AS 
( 
    SELECT cid, SUM(mf) AS smf 
    FROM Q2 
    GROUP BY cid 
)
SELECT Q1.cid, sumEP + smf AS total 
FROM Q1 
JOIN Q3 ON Q1.cid = Q3.cid 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at this.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your current code from a style point of view.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah but its more like an exercise but i really dont know how to convert this example its really hard to me

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks but, i kinda need to combine Q1 Q2 and Q3 into one thing do you have any ideas?

Comment: Q1 and Q3 are essentially the same. Nevermind, Q3 sums freight.

Comment: @RossBush yeah thats the problem, you have any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smf` is the sum of distinct values of `freight` per order (for the same customer), but this you can do with `sum(distinct freight)`

So I would suggest this query:

```
WITH Q(customerid, orderid, total) AS 
(
    SELECT   customerid, orderid, SUM(Extendedprice) + SUM(DISTINCT freight)
    FROM     Invoices
    GROUP BY customerid, orderid 
)
SELECT customerid, SUM(total) AS total
FROM   Q
GROUP BY customerid
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

When there are no cases where different orders for the same customer have the same freight value, then it can be simplified to:

```
SELECT   customerid, SUM(Extendedprice) + SUM(DISTINCT freight) AS total
FROM     Invoices
GROUP BY customerid 
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Note I added an `order by` so that you limit the results with some logic behind it -- in this case getting the top-10 by total. Change as needed.

Comment: @Mezus . . . `SUM(DISTINCT)` is, in my opinion, **never** correct in a SQL statement.  It might happen to work, but small changes to the data would invalidate it.

Comment: . . The OP has not included sample data, but if two orders for the same customer have the same freight costs, then I don't think this produces a reasonable result.

Comment: . . It is not a problem for the query in the question.  It is a problem for your query.

Comment: Thank you, @Gordon, I updated my answer.